# Limit of ln summation

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I am trying to find the limit $$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=\left\lceil \sqrt{n}\right\rceil }^{n}\ln\left(\frac{n}{i}\right) $$ I can't  find a good way to handle it. I tried bounding it from below and from above, but the bounds I got to are not tight enough.

Comment: You mean $i = \lceil n \rceil$?

Comment: $i=\left\lceil \sqrt{n}\right\rceil $, edited

Comment: Oops yes, I mistyped

Comment: I guess it's $1$. As $$\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=\left\lceil \sqrt{n}\right\rceil}^n\log\left(\dfrac{n}{i}\right)=\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\log\left(\dfrac{n}{i}\right)-\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{\left\lfloor\,\sqrt{n}\right\rfloor }\log\left(\dfrac{n}{i}\right)$$
and use Stirling formula, the first and the second as $n\rightarrow\infty$ are $1$ and $0$ respectively.

Answer (score 1):

If you know about Pochhammer symbols
$$\sum_{i=a}^n\log\left(\dfrac{n}{i}\right)=\log \left(\frac{n^{n-a+1}}{a (a+1)_{n-a}}\right)$$
$$\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=\left\lceil \sqrt{n}\right\rceil}^n\log\left(\dfrac{n}{i}\right)=\frac 1n\log\left(\frac{\Gamma \left(\left\lceil
   \sqrt{n}\right\rceil \right)}{\Gamma (n)}\,n^{n-\left\lceil \sqrt{n}\right\rceil }\right) $$

Now, use Stirling approximation.

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially a Riemann sum. Noting that $f(x) = \log(1/x)$ is decreasing, we have

$$ \int_{\frac{i}{n}}^{\frac{i+1}{n}} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x
\leq \frac{1}{n}f\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)
\leq \int_{\frac{i-1}{n}}^{\frac{i}{n}} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x. $$

So, if we denote the sum by $S_n$, then

$$ \int_{\frac{\lceil\sqrt{n}\rceil}{n}}^{1+\frac{1}{n}} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x
\leq S_n
\leq \int_{\frac{\lceil\sqrt{n}\rceil-1}{n}}^{1} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x. $$

Since $f(x)$ is either improper Riemann-integrable or Lebesgue-integrable over $(0, 1]$, it follows from the squeezing theorem that

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} S_n = \int_{0}^{1} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = 1. $$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\sum_{i=[\sqrt{n}]}^n \ln (n/i)\ge \sum_{i=[\sqrt{n}]}^n \ln (\sqrt{n})=\frac{1}{2}(n-[\sqrt{n}]+1)\ln n>\frac{n}{4}\ln n
$$
the last inequality, for $n\ge 4$.

Hence
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=[\sqrt{n}]}^n \ln (n/i)\ge \frac{1}{4}\ln n\to\infty.
$$

Comment: The first inequality is wrong, for every $i \geq \sqrt{n}$, $ \ln{n/i} \leq \ln{\sqrt{n}}$. Also, the limit is 1 and not $ \infty $